# Catch Duplicate entry with prepared SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I want to handle the "Duplicate entry" error with a prepared MySQL statement.

I have thoses lines

```
$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comptability (id_comptability, order_id, Reduction, `%TVA`, Facture) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$result->execute(array($no_facture, $id_order, $reduc_tot, $tot, $date));
```

And want to execute some code if there is not any error. And display a pop-up and make the prog die if there is an error.

I already tried

```
if($result === false)//Catch error
{}
else //It worked
{}
```

But it did not worked

Comment: You are checking the PDO statement itself. You should check for the return value. But beetter would be to use `errorCode` and `errorInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` and then check how many rows were affected using [PDOStatement::rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Concept should be along the lines of:

```
$result = $db->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO comptability (id_comptability, order_id, Reduction, `%TVA`, Facture) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
if ($result->execute(array($no_facture, $id_order, $reduc_tot, $tot, $date))) {
  if ($result->rowCount() == 0) {
   // You had a duplicate record.
  } else {
   // all good.
  }
}
```